# How to transpose a named range in Excel 2013, using cell formulas (not VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, named-ranges, transpose

Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/951286/when-using-a-named-ranged-in-excel-2013-how-to-display-the-entire-range-but) question, I want to display the values of a named range (horizontal) in a vertical range.

If I have data `a b d f` which is named `Letters` (as a named range). I want to display this named range transposed (i.e. proceeding downward with the `V`'s), how do I do this?

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|d|f| | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|V| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|V| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|V| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|V| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I've tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> answer suggested by @Excellll in the referenced question, but when the fill handle is dragged downwards, only the `a` value propagates downward. If the `TRANSPOSE()` function is the answer, nothing I've tried with it has worked yet (`{=TRANSPOSE(Letters)}` for example

Comment: What is `{=TRANSPOSE(Letters)}` returning? It works for me in my tests. Make sure you are selecting the entire output range before entering the formula.

Comment: Strange; it didn't work before, the output was all `a a a a`, but it's working now. Thank you. I will update the original question if that is the proper documentation procedure...